# how can I modify my parameter without writing whole line again?

Tags: python-3.x, parameters, pygame

Hi I'm trying some method overwriting but I dont know how to do it. I have this class called RectCreator

```
class RectCreator:

    def __init__(self, location_x, location_y, width, height, ):
        self.location_x = location_x
        self.location_y = location_y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
  
    def creating_rect(self, display, color):
        creating_rect = pygame.Rect(self.location_x, self.location_y, self.width, self.height)
        drawing_rect = pygame.draw.rect(display, color, creating_rect, border_radius=20)
        return creating_rect, drawing_rect
```

this class is in a file. I imported the file in my main.py and I'm using the class like this:

```
button_1 = RectCreator(350, 350, 100, 100)
btn_1 = button_1.creating_rect(display_surface, blue)
```

Now here is what I want to do. I dont know how to change the color of the btn_1 without writing all the line again like this:

```
btn_1 = button_1.creating_rect(display_surface, green) ---------------> I DONT WANT TO WRITE THAT
```

I tried to add a color method to the class and put that method in the method that uses color.

```
def color(self, color):
    return color

def creating_rect(self, display):
    creating_rect = pygame.Rect(self.location_x, self.location_y, self.width, self.height)
    drawing_rect = pygame.draw.rect(display, self.color(), creating_rect, border_radius=20)
    return creating_rect, drawing_rect
```

That was my solution but self.color() asks me for a parameter. All I want to do is:

```
btn_1 = button_1.creating_rect(display_surface, blue)
**output : a blue box that display on my app**

btn_1.change_color(green)
**output : now that blue box turned to green box**
```

Comment: Why do you not wat to write that. What about adding a `color` attribute?

Comment: actually no specific reason. but it really helps me to be open to different solutions.

Comment: You can use a default argument (`def creating_rect(self, display, color=green)`) or an attribute (`self.color`)

Comment: ok @Rabbid76 I will try that. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you draw something on the screen (like a rect), it's there to stay and won't go away until you draw something new at the same position. E.g. if you set the pixel of the screen at position `5, 12` to the color green, you can't magically change the color at that position without interacting with the screen surface again.

So if you draw a blue rect and now want a green rect, you have to call `pygame.draw.rect` again. Changing a random variable is not enough.

What you could do is add a color attribute to your class and use that to change the color of the rect *that you have to draw every frame anyway* (exceptions may exist):

```
class RectCreator:

    def __init__(self, location_x, location_y, width, height, color='blue'):
        self.rect = pygame.Rect((location_x, location_y, width, height))
        self.color = color
  
    def draw(self, display):
        pygame.draw.rect(display, self.color, self.rect, border_radius=20)
```

Then, create an instance and in your main loop, keep calling `draw`. You can then change the color simply by setting the `color` attribute

```
import random
...
btn_1 = RectCreator(350, 350, 100, 100)
...
while True:

    for e in pygame.event.get():
        if e.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            btn_1.color = random.choice(('blue', 'green', 'red', 'yellow'))

    btn_1.draw(display_surface)
    ...
    pygame.display.flip()
```